# How to use ng-show and hide ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to show and hide play and pause button, when play is clicked i need to hide pause button and vice-versa. I tried like this

```
<ion-content padding>    
    <button ion-button *ngIf="status"  name="play" (click)="itemSelected()" >Play</button> 
    <button ion-button *ngIf="!status" name="square" (click)="stopPlayback()" >stop</button>        
</ion-content>

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {

  status: boolean = false;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                public alertCtrl: AlertController,
                public navParams: NavParams,) {                  

                }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
    }
 itemSelected(){
      this.status = true
    }
    stopPlayback(){
      console.log("stop");
      this.status = false
    }

}
```

could some one help me to resolve this issue, thanks in advance

[image: every time i click stop only stop is visiable]

Comment: please post `itemSelected()`, `stopPlayback()` code

Comment: check now, but still i get 1 button visiable @Tiep Phan 1

Comment: hey man, did you touch this variable `status` in other method

Comment: post full code please, i don't have time to guess what wrong in your code

Comment: its just a single page app with two button, but one button should be visible on clicking another button should be shown

Comment: btw, your code won't do anything, because your logic is wrong, the status does not change if you implement like above. correct like this `itemSelected() {
    this.status = false;
  }
  stopPlayback() {
    this.status = true;
  }`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/s82OS8XaeGBMm90L2DFm?p=preview

Comment: you need somehow change the value, if `*ngIf="status"` this mean, `status = true` then you wanna this button hide when clicked, the action must be `status = false`, same for `*ngIf="!status"`

Comment: it worked :)   thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Angular 2 does not have ng-show, ng-hide, use *ngIf instead

```
<ion-icon *ngIf="!checkStatus" (click)="play()" name="play" ></ion-icon> 
<ion-icon *ngIf="checkStatus" (click)="pause()" name="square"></ion-icon>
```

or you could create css style then binding class css to element

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

then in template:

```
<ion-icon [class.hide]="!checkStatus" (click)="play()" name="play" ></ion-icon> 
<ion-icon [class.hide]="checkStatus" (click)="pause()" name="square"></ion-icon>
```

this maybe wrong

```
play(){
    console.log("play");
    this.status = false;
}
pause(){
    console.log("pause");
    this.status = false;
}
```

change to this

```
play(){
    console.log("play");
    this.status = false;
}
pause(){
    console.log("pause");
    this.status = true;
}
```

demo here: https://plnkr.co/edit/L59w8tmCkbEkNX5CQ1D6?p=preview

do not binding to `hidden` property if you don't wanna apply `!important`

http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

> At first glance, binding to the `hidden` property seems like the
>   closest cousin to Angular 1's ng-show.  However, there is one
>   "!important" difference.
>
> `ng-show` and `ng-hide` both manage visibility by toggling an
>   `"ng-hide"` CSS class on the element,  which simply sets the display
>   property to "none" when applied.  Crucially, Angular controls this
>   style and postscripts it with `"!important"` to ensure it always
>   overrides any other display styles set on that element.

Comment: i need play to visible then pause to be hidden, after play click opposite should be hidden but both the buttons are visible when i use above

Comment: play(){
        console.log("play");
        this.status = true; // maybe this one
    }
    pause(){
        console.log("pause");
        this.status = false;
    }

Comment: btw, i don't see any `checkStatus` property

Comment: i removed this.status in both pause and play but both buttons are visible

Comment: please wait, i'll give you plnk example

Answer (score 11):

Ionic2 uses Angular2, and Angular2 doesn't have the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` directives. Instead, you can use either `ngIf` (removes and adds items from the DOM) or `hidden` (works like `ng-hide`).

In your code:

```
<ion-icon [hidden]="checkStatus" (click)="play()" name="play" ></ion-icon> 
<ion-icon [hidden]="!checkStatus" (click)="pause()" name="square"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: do not binding to hidden property if you do wanna apply `!important` css rule

Comment: You are right, but that's the closest thing Angular2 has to `ng-hide`. `ngIf` removes and adds items to the DOM, which can have bad performance if it happens a lot.

Comment: use binding css instead, see my answer below

Comment: pause button gets hidden play is visible but when i click on play its not getting hidden no pause button is visible

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<ion-list no-lines>
 <button ion-button clear item-end class="roundButton" (click)="viewType = !viewType">
  <ion-icon name="add-circle" item-right></ion-icon>
 </button>
 <ion-item *ngIf="viewType">
  <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```